# Android: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean

Tags: java, android, webview

I am getting the following error:

```
*E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: xxx.mxxxa.xxx, PID: 10610
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean    java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference*
```

on the following lines:

```
public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

                if (datingView.getUrl().contains("messages.php") && datingView.getUrl().contains("messages.php" +
                        "")){
                    bannerReklam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else if (datingView.getUrl().contains("upgrade.php") && datingView.getUrl().contains("upgrade.php" +
                        "")){
                    bannerReklam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else if (datingView.getUrl().contains("index.php") && datingView.getUrl().contains("index.php" +
                        "")){
                    bannerReklam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else if (datingView.getUrl().contains("join.php") && datingView.getUrl().contains("join.php" +
                        "") ){
                    bannerReklam.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }else{

                    bannerReklam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                // if url contains string androidexample
                // Then show progress  Dialog
                if (progressDialog == null && url.contains("instasquare")
                        ) {

                    // in standard case YourActivity.this
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(arkadasBulMain.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }
```

This problem causes the application to stop. This error occurs for versions below android 9.0.

Comment: And what about the error is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases  `datingView.getUrl()` return `null`. First try to check `null` and then try to search item using `contains`. For Example:

```
String datingUrl = datingView.getUrl();

if(datingUrl != null && datingUrl.contains("messages.php"))
```

Comment: do I need to make this query for each row?

Comment: No, first check null and if it is null then skip rest of the operation